# How to use AWS SQS Queue attributes to trigger a stack from Cloud Formation templates

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-cli

I am using AWS CLI  to automate my resource provisioning, my requirement is to use AWS SQS to trigger the automation script with parameters.But i am not sure how to deal with this problem.
Can i send the parameters in a JSON file and parse them using a parser???

TIA

Comment: you ever figure this out? I am trying to parse SQS messsages using aws cli.